# Binding Error Reported with Converter in WPF Textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, converters

a textbox is either hidden or not depending on whether its text is null or not.
The actual hiding works ok but i keep getting a Data.Error as follows.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'new_file_path' property not found on 'object' ''main_window_vm' (HashCode=44962972)'. BindingExpression:Path=new_file_path; DataItem='main_window_vm' (HashCode=44962972); target element is 'Run' (HashCode=28141317); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

xaml is

```xml
<Padding="10" Visibility="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
     Converter={StaticResource null_to_viz}}">
<Run Text="Updated file path : " />
<Run Text="{Binding new_file_path}" />
```

any ideas to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is complaining about not finding `new_file_path` yet the example is binding to the property `Text`.

Most likely this converter is not failing and it is a different control. Investigate by either finding the right control which is not binding properly or verifying that textbox is actually binding to the proper VM.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this error occurs when one foolishly set a property to private, not public.  Which is why it was not able to be found.